# Curl is not recognizing the parameter I am passing

Tags: curl, http-post, http-request-parameters

I am trying to send a post request to an endpoint that takes in the data as formdata with key RequestDO... it works when I complete the request in Postman, but when I execute this request I get this error and I cannot figure out why. Do you cURL experts see what the issue is with my request?

`curl -H "Content-Type:application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer {token}" -F "requestDO=@/Users/me/Desktop/testing.json" -X POST myUrl`

*{"type":"about:blank","title":"Bad Request","status":400,"detail":"Required parameter 'requestDO' is not present."*